# Clarification of finding this transition probability matrix

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-probability, transition-matrix

Let $X_n$ denote the two-state Markov chain with transition probability matrix
P=
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 1-\alpha\\
1-\beta & \beta
\end{bmatrix}
$
given states 0 and 1. Let $Z_n=(X_{n-1},X_n)$ be a Markov chain over the four states (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), and (1,1). Determine the transition probability matrix.

Here are my thoughts so far:
If $Z_n=(X_{n-1},X_n)$, then $Z_{n-1}=(X_{n-2},X_{n-1})$. 
I believe I'm looking for $P[Z_n=(x_1,y_1)|Z_{n-1}=(x_2,y_2)]=\frac{P[X_{n-1}=x_1, X_n=y_1, X_{n-2}=x_2, X_{n-1}=y_2]}{P[X_{n-2}=x_2, X_{n-1}=y_2]}$=$P(X_n=y_1|X_{n-1}=x_1, X_{n-2}=x_2)$=$P(X_n=y_1|X_{n-1}=x_1)$ by the Markov property.

For example, using the points (0,0)$\rightarrow$(0,0) would be
$P[Z_n=(0,0)|Z_{n-1}=(0,0)]=\frac{P[X_{n-1}=0, X_n=0, X_{n-2}=0, X_{n-1}=0]}{P[X_{n-2}=0, X_{n-1}=0]}$=$P(X_n=0|X_{n-1}=0, X_{n-2}=0)$=$P(X_n=0|X_{n-1}=0)$ which corresponds to $p_{00}=\alpha$.

Following this process I obtained 
P=$\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha &0 &\alpha &0\\
1-\alpha &0 &1-\alpha &0\\
0 &1-\beta &0 &1-\beta\\
0 &\beta &0 &\beta\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

$0$'s denote a probability that is not possible (i.e. $X_{n-1}$ cannot be both 0 and 1).

I've seen the answer expressed as the matrix P=
$\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha &1-\alpha &0 &0\\
0 &0 &1-\beta &\beta\\
\alpha &1-\alpha &0 &0\\
0 &0 &1-\beta &\beta\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Based on the logic in when a probability equals zero I really think my transition probability matrix is correct rather than the alternative choice. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your matrix is just the transpose of the answer. It occurs probably because your definition is different from the answer's.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestions as how I could modify this? I'm very new to Markov chains.

Comment: You should be able to tell at a glance that there’s something wrong with your proposed solution because the rows sums of $P$ aren’t all $1$.

Comment: Thanks, I gathered that a little bit later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix is just the transpose of the answer. It occurs probably because your definition is different from the answer's. For instance, for the transition probability matrix $P$, the row sums equal to 1. It means that 
$$
\sum_{j} p_{ij} = 1
$$
because it is summing over all possible outcomes of $i \to j$. It does not matter in computing the probability for $(0,0) \to (0,0)$, but it does matter for $(1,0) \to (0,0)$. Examine your calculation and make sure that it is defined as 
$$
p_{ij} = \mathbb{P}(Z_{n+1}=j|Z_n=i)
$$
Yours may be the other way around and result in the transpose.

Comment: That makes sense I was definitely doing $p_{ij}=P(Z_n=j|Z_{n+1}=i)$. (Also, how did you write the hollowed out P?)

Comment: @Strakatastic It is \mathbb{P}